# Move cursor position on every click of button Java

Tags: java, android-sqlite, database-cursor

I created an application of student management on Android studio and i want to enter students' marks to the database on every click of a button.

This is the piece of code i wrote for the cursor, So the cursor is in the first row in the table and i want it to move to the next position on every click of a button .

```
Cursor cursor = DB.DisplayEtudiant(matricule);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
while(cursor.moveToNext()){
        editMatricule.setText(cursor.getString(0));
        editNote.setText(" ");
}
```

The while loop here does not work and i cannot understand why.

Answer (score 1):

You are moving to the first row in the cursor, then moving to the next row.
If only 1 row is retrieved then you skip that row and do nothing.

If there are multiple rows in the extracted cursor then you are effectively moving to the last row and setting the editMatricule's text to " ". Thus irrespective of the notion of a current position in the cursor you will always move to the last rather than the next.

It's impossible to provide a fix to your issue because so much would be left to speculation. However, perhaps consider the following that allows traversal  (i.e. not only Next but also First, Previous and Last):-

**First** a simple layout with a TextView that shows the Student (Etudiant) with an EditText for the mark.

Below the Student details are 4 buttons First,Prev,Next and Last:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!">
    </TextView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/etudiant_name"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="8"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </TextView>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etudiant_mark"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/first_etudiant"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="FIRST"
            >
        </Button>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/prev_etudiant"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="PREV"
            >
        </Button>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/next_etudiant"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="NEXT"
            >
        </Button>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/last_etudiant"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="LAST"
            >
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Next** the DatabaseHelper **DBHelper** :-

```
class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "thedatabase.db";
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public static final String TABLE_NAME_MATRICULE = "matricule";
    public static final String MATRICULE_COL_ID = BaseColumns._ID;
    public static final String MATRICULE_COL_MARK = "matricule_MARK";
    public static final String MATRICULE_COL_ETUDIANT = "matricule_etudiant";

    DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME_MATRICULE + " ("
                + MATRICULE_COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
                + MATRICULE_COL_ETUDIANT + " TEXT, "
                + MATRICULE_COL_MARK + " INTEGER " +
                ");"
        );
        db.execSQL("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO " + TABLE_NAME_MATRICULE
                + "(" + MATRICULE_COL_ETUDIANT + "," + MATRICULE_COL_MARK + ")" +
                " VALUES ('Etudiant1',0),('Etudiant2',0),('Etudiant3',0),('Etudiant4',0)"
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {

    }

    public Cursor DisplayEtudiant() {
        return this.getWritableDatabase().query(TABLE_NAME_MATRICULE,null,null,null,null,null,null);
    }
}
```

- Note that the table is just to demonstrate the technique and is unlikely to reflect your table(s). The `DisplayEtudiant` again is just to demonstrate.

**Last** the activity **MainActivity**. This using the layout above and thus inclduing onClick listeners for the 4 buttons which traverse the cursor changing the display accordingly:-

```
@SuppressLint("Range")
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DBHelper DB;
    Cursor cursor;
    int current_matricule_position = 0;
    int matricule_count = 0;
    TextView etduiant_name;
    EditText etudiant_mark;
    Button first,prev,next,last;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        etduiant_name = this.findViewById(R.id.etudiant_name);
        etudiant_mark = this.findViewById(R.id.etudiant_mark);
        first = this.findViewById(R.id.first_etudiant);
        prev = this.findViewById(R.id.prev_etudiant);
        next = this.findViewById(R.id.next_etudiant);
        last = this.findViewById(R.id.last_etudiant);
        DB = new DBHelper(this);
        setOrRefreshCursor();
        displayCurrent();
        setupButtons();
    }


    private void setupButtons() {
        first.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (matricule_count > 0) {
                    cursor.moveToFirst();
                    current_matricule_position = 0;
                    displayCurrent();
                }
            }
        });
        prev.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (matricule_count > 0) {
                    if (current_matricule_position > 0) {
                        current_matricule_position--;
                        cursor.moveToPrevious();
                        displayCurrent();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (matricule_count > 0) {
                    if (current_matricule_position < (matricule_count - 1)) {
                        current_matricule_position++;
                        cursor.moveToNext();
                        displayCurrent();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        last.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (matricule_count > 0) {
                    cursor.moveToLast();
                    current_matricule_position = cursor.getPosition();
                    displayCurrent();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void displayCurrent() {
        etduiant_name.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.MATRICULE_COL_ETUDIANT)));
        etudiant_mark.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.MATRICULE_COL_MARK)));
    }

    private void setOrRefreshCursor() {
        cursor = DB.DisplayEtudiant();
        if (current_matricule_position < 0) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        } else {
            cursor.moveToPosition(current_matricule_position);
        }
        current_matricule_position = cursor.getPosition();
        matricule_count = cursor.getCount();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        cursor.close();
    }
}
```

The App when run displays :-

[image]

Clicking a button moves to the respective etudiant if the move should/can be made (e.g. when at the first etudian First and Prev will do nothing, likewise when at the last etudiant Last and Next do nothing).